# How to obtain joint pdf given by two marginal pdf

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to obtain a joint pdf given by two marginal pdfs.
Assume, X and Y are RV and they are following U[0,1].

Is there a way to parameterize the correlation of X and Y into the joint pdf?

For example, something like f(X,Y) = aX + aY + bXY, where -2 < b < 2 and b=-2 gets corr(X,Y)=-1, b=2 gets corr(X,Y)=1, and b=0 gets corr(X,Y)=0.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is *copula*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)

Comment: Thanks, Jukka. Can I ask how can I back out cdf (or pdf) out of copula? For example, if I use Ali–Mikhail–Haq bivariate copula, how can I obtain it. In addition, how exactly theta plays a role in terms of the correlation?